# Staking and ERC20 Approve (RPC Error: execution reverted: ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance)

Tags: erc-20, dapps, erc-20-approve, frontend

I apologize if this question might seem a bit simple beforehand. I'm trying call the `deposit` function from my frontend, but it gives me the error mentioned above. I am confused as to if this is a problem on my next.js front-end or on my smart contracts.

This is what the relevant parts of my front end looks like:

```
async function depositToJuniorPool(amount) {
  if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') {
      const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
      const signer = provider.getSigner()
      const juniorPool = new ethers.Contract(juniorPoolAddress, JuniorPool.abi, signer)
      console.log('juniorPool: ', juniorPool)
      try {
        
          const val = await juniorPool.deposit(amount)
          console.log('val: ', val)
        } catch (err) {
          console.log('Error: ', err)
        }
}
        <div className={buttonContainer}>
                <button className={buttonStyle}
                type='button'
                onClick={() => depositToJuniorPool(110)}>Stake
                </button>
        </div>
```

This is what the relevant parts of my smart contracts look like:

```
 function deposit(uint256 amount) external override whenNotPaused withinTransactionLimit(amount) nonReentrant {
    require(amount >= 110, "Must deposit 110 or more");
    // Check if the amount of new shares to be added is within limits
    uint256 depositShares = getNumShares(amount);
    uint256 potentialNewTotalShares = totalShares().add(depositShares);
    require(poolWithinLimit(potentialNewTotalShares), "Deposit would put the Pool over the total limit.");
    emit DepositMade(msg.sender, amount, depositShares);
    bool success = doUSDCTransfer(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
    require(success, "Failed to transfer for deposit");


    config.getJuniorToken().juniorPoolMintTo(msg.sender, depositShares);
  }

  function doUSDCTransfer(
    address from,
    address to,
    uint256 amount
  ) internal returns (bool) {
    require(to != address(0), "Can't send to zero address");
    IERC20withDec usdc = config.getUSDC();
    usdc.approve(from, amount);
    return usdc.transferFrom(from, to, amount);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
usdc.approve(from, amount);
```

What this is doing is having juniorPool itself call approve for usdc, where it's giving `from` an allowance to move `amount` from the juniorPool's own balance. Take a look at OpenZeppelin's ERC20.sol

```
function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) {
    address owner = _msgSender();
    _approve(owner, spender, amount);
    return true;
}
```

`msg.sender` approves spender to move `amount`. juniorPool is the one calling approve, so juniorPool is `msg.sender` in this case and is allowing the address calling `await juniorPool.deposit(amount)` to move tokens from the the contract.

You want the address calling `await juniorPool.deposit(amount)` to approve juniorPool. In ethers create a USDC contract instance, with USDC's ABI or a generic ERC20 ABI, and then call deposit with your contract instance.

```
// signer approves the contract to move amount
await usdc.approve(<juniorPool address>, amount)

// signer calls deposit from contract
await juniorPool.deposit(amount)
```

Comment: I want to mention you could also call ```<contract>.connect(<address of user or contract>).approve()``` to change the user context (in other words the address of ```msg.sender```)

Comment: Can you explain how this would work @Gleichmut ?
The contract (juniorPool) is already connected to the signer's address. From there, juniorPool calls a USDC contract instance. The msg.sender for that USDC contract call from within juniorPool would still be juniorPool

Comment: There is no disagreement between you and me in understanding of this. What I would like to point out in comment above is ```ether.js``` provides an option where you can explicitly tell from which account you would like to call this contract function.